# Can I access a remote web server over an SSH connection?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, webserver, openssh

I recently set up a remote server, which I have running the bare minimums currently.  I set up OpenSSH and can access the machine through one of my domain names (using an A-type DNS record).  I also have a web server running on the machine, but all ports except SSH are blocked at the gateway.

While in the future I plan to open port 80, for now as I'm in "development" mode, and I would like to disallow any outside access or traffic to the web server through port 80 (or over the HTTP protocol for that matter).  Right now, the only way to access the machine *externally* is through an SSH connection.

Now, I was wondering: how can I redirect the local HTTP server traffic *through* SSH so I can access my web server locally?  Can this be done even if I have port 80 firewalled at the router/gateway?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

yes, using ssh port forwarding.

```
ssh -L 80:localhost:80 name-of-remote-system
```

This will send any browser connection to port 80 on your local machine over ssh to the remote machine.  Once there, it will continue to localhost (the machine you used ssh to connect to), port 80.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I had heard of SSH tunneling before, but hadn't used it since now.  Note that I did have to use `sudo` to run this command.

Comment: Actually, as a small follow-up to my previous comment; running the command without `sudo` will cause the error `Privelaged ports can only be forwarded by root.` to appear.  However, once I prepended `sudo` to the SSH command, I noticed my RSA-key credentials were being rejected.  Note that unless your `sudo` user shares the same SSH keys, you will need to specify the path to your current keyfile using the `-i` argument (e.g. append `-i /home/YOUR_USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa` to the end of the command).

Comment: What does -L mean?

Comment: @Flan1335 In OpenSSH, local port forwarding is configured using the -L option. https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example

Comment: Does it just forward raw packets or add some headers? Raw packets are not modified yet, HTTP or SOCKS proxies modify the packet to add some headers.