# Can I access a remote VPS's 127.0.0.1 via proxy?

Tags: ssh, proxy, localhost, vps

127.0.0.1 points to local machine, is it possible to access a remote VPS's 127.0.0.1 instead of my own device?

Comment: Yes, if you own the VPS, you could for example use something like https://ngrok.com/

Comment: Can SSH mentioned here: https://superuser.com/a/621808/1794000 access a remote VPS's 127.0.0.1?

Comment: We are running into an XY problem. https://xyproblem.info/ What is your goal? What do you want to do? Do you own the VPS? Google "SSH tunneling" and "port forwarding". 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address, meaning it always points to itself. If I host a website on my computer I open one of many ports (e.g. 80) and then I configure my router to do portforwarding (which allows outgoing and incoming connections). ngrok makes that a bit easier. https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example

Comment: I wanna use post-quantum ciphers like Kyber, which is Lattice-based. But some countries, e.g., China, Iran, Russia, Syria, UAE, have strict Internet censorship, and may block Lattice-based ciphers. So I wanna use tools like SSH to pretend that I'm using RSA or ECC (which are vulnerable to quantum computers), over SSH connection, running Lattice-based ciphers, to bypass censorship in China, Iran, Russia, Syria, UAE, etc.

Comment: None of that changes where 127.0.0.1 is - it is always "here". It is not a routable address. Every NIC has its own 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Well, imagine if my computer runs a webserver to host my website on port 80. I can go to 127.0.0.1:80 (directly from my computer to my computer). Now imagine I configure port forwarding on my router. In order to reach my website from your computer you'd need my external ip address (not 127.0.0.1!) but you would still end up at the same website that is hosted on 127.0.0.1 according to *my* computer. So "127.0.0.1" means the same as the word "me" in English. To me, that word means Gantendo, but to you it means Flan1335.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: And of course https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/security.png If Syria is fooled into thinking I am using inferior encryption, and they try to decrypt that and fail, they will use this very effective technique

Comment: Places like that will see you are using SSH and consider that suspicious. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell SSH wasn't designed with the goal of hiding itself in mind. Security, not stealth.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. However, what protocol is this question about? SSH, as tagged? Or maybe HTTP, because it’s tagged _proxy_? // How does your question relate to your plan to bypass censorship?

Answer (score 2):

The `ssh` utility can be used to forward individual TCP ports. A command such as the following:

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:80 user@your-vps
```

will listen for TCP connections on port 8080 of the local system. Any connection received on port 8080 will be forwarded to IP 127.0.0.1 port 80 on the remote system, i.e. your VPS.

If you want to forward more than one port, you can specify "-L" more than once:

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:80 -L 8081:127.0.0.1:81 user@your-vps
```

This command would forward ports 8080 and 8081 to ports 80 and 81 on the remote system.

Comment: That question was asked [here](https://superuser.com/a/621808/1794000) and answered there

Comment: Do I need to configure SSH on VPS to receive the forwarded packets?

Comment: Yes, the VPS server has to be configured to accept SSH sessions, and you'll have to be able to log into the VPS as some user.

Comment: Does it just forward raw packets or add some headers? Raw packets are not modified yet, HTTP or SOCKS proxies modify the packet to add some headers.